# Is there a way to change a function by clicking on different divs?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I just started school, and this is my first question ever asked on Stackoverflow, so I apologize up front regarding both formatting and wording of this question.

I want to change the border color of my div to a style I have already declared when I click on it. To show that this has been selected.

I have three divs with id="red/green/pink".

Now, is there a way to change this function to grab information from the div I clicked, so I dont have to write 3 (almost) identical functions?

```
.chosenBorder{
border: 3px solid gold;
}

<div id="red" class="mainDivs" onclick="newColor('red')">Red?</div>
<div id="green" class="mainDivs" onclick="newColor('green')">Green?</div>
<div id="pink" class="mainDivs" onclick="newColor('pink')">Pink?</div>
<div class="mainDivs" onclick="whatNow(changeBig)">Choose!</div>

<script>
  let changeBig = "";
  let chosenDiv = document.getElementById("body");

  function newColor(thisColor) {
    changeBig = thisColor;
    // something that make this part dynamic.classList.toggle("chosenBorder");
  }

  function whatNow(changeBig) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = changeBig;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You can access clicked `div` with `this`

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have an `id` contains the name of color; get the advantage of it: and keep track of the selected color in your variable `changeBig`.

```js
let changeBig = "";

function newColor(div) {
  // initial all divs to black
  initialDivs();
  div.style.borderColor = div.id;
  changeBig = div.id;
}

function initialDivs() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.mainDivs')].forEach(div => {
    div.style.borderColor = 'black'
  });
}

function whatNow() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = changeBig;
}
```

```css
.mainDivs {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid;
  outline: 3px solid;
  width: fit-content;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="red" class="mainDivs" onclick="newColor(this)">Red?</div>
<div id="green" class="mainDivs" onclick="newColor(this)">Green?</div>
<div id="pink" class="mainDivs" onclick="newColor(this)">Pink?</div>
<div class="mainDivs" onclick="whatNow()">Choose!</div>
```

Comment: thanks! However I guess I didnt make myself clear, I want to change the border into something else, I called this class .chosenBorder, and hopefully I can toggle it by pressed too. Unless its better to just write a if-statement.

Comment: Welcome! it's better to store the style info in CSS as Andy said.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few (modern) modifications you can make to simplify things.

1. Remove the inline JS.
2. Use CSS to store the style information.
3. [Use data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the colour rather than the id.
4. Wrap the div elements (I've called them boxes here) in [a containing element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). This way you can use a technique called [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). By [attaching *one* listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the container you can have that listen to events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM. When an event is caught it calls a function that 1) checks that the event is from a box element 2) [retrieves the color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from [the element's dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), and adds it to its [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) along with an `active` class.

```js
// Cache the elements
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
const container = document.querySelector('.boxes');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// Add a listener to the container which calls
// `handleClick` when it catches an event fired from one of
// its child elements, and a listener to the button to change
// the background
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
button.addEventListener('click', handleBackground);

function handleClick(e) {

  // Check to see if the child element that fired
  // the event has a box class
  if (e.target.matches('.box')) {

    // Remove the color and active classes from
    // all the boxes
    boxes.forEach(box => box.className = 'box');

    // Destructure the color from its dataset, and
    // add that to the class list of the clicked box
    // along with an active class
    const { color } = e.target.dataset;
    e.target.classList.add(color, 'active');
  }
    
}

function handleBackground() {
  
  // Get the active box, get its color, and then assign
  // that color to the body background
  const active = document.querySelector('.box.active');
  const { color } = active.dataset;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
.boxes { display: flex; flex-direction: row; background-color: white; padding: 0.4em;}
.box { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 2px solid #dfdfdf; margin-right: 0.25em; }
button { margin-top: 1em; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.box:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.red { border: 2px solid red; }
.green { border: 2px solid green; }
.pink { border: 2px solid pink; }
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box" data-color="red">Red</div>
  <div class="box" data-color="green">Green</div>
  <div class="box" data-color="pink">Pink</div>
</div>
<button>Change background</button>
```

Comment: Good notes, Just the OP want to change the backround based on the color chosen!

Comment: _"I want to change the border color of my div"_ is what the question says @TAHERElMehdi

Comment: Which my code does @TAHERElMehdi

Comment: Yes just I found the code change backround, so I guess He want to change backround from the color chosen!